# windows bat to create repo with git

Tags: git, batch-file, bitbucket

I have this windows bat to push into bitbucket:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m   %RANDOM%
git remote add origin %1\
git push -u origin master
```

But, it fails due to %1\ having "" inside.
How can I correct this bat to remove "" and make it work ?

Comment: Just remove the trailing ``\``?

Comment: `%~1` removes any surrounding quotes (if present)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after

```
git remote add origin "%1"
```

Since %1 probably has several characters that cause problems without.